# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, zend-framework, cloud

I am getting this error when trying to authenticate with a Zend Framework 1.12.X, deployed in PHP cloud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I solved my own problem... I  got this working this way, for the hostname/host try to use your credentials found in the Zend Server -> PHP Cloud tab -> Overview page -> User Parameters tab... then make the "host" part in the credentials like this:

```
[general]
 db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
 db.params.host = CONTAINERNAME-db.my.phpcloud.com
 db.params.username = ZEND_DB_USERNAME
 db.params.password = ZEND_DB_USERNAME
 db.params.dbname = ZEND_DB_DBNAME
```